# WPF: Trigger animation - Move Control downwards along Y axis

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a control that I want to move downwards upon `MouseOver`. Unfortunately the animation doesnt run when I mouse over, the background changes colour though.

`Toolkit:Dialog` is a custom dialog control inheriting `ContentControl`. Also, in final implementation I wont be using MouseOver - that is currently just for ease of testing.

```
<Style x:Key="blah" TargetType="Toolkit:Dialog">
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Toolkit:CanvasControl.Background" Value="White" />
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="0" To="100" Duration="00:00:01.000" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style>
```

Comment: Not enough information. On what control/style is that trigger used? Remember that when you apply an animation on mouse over, that the element moves, which could end in that the mouse is not over anymore. Can lead to some annoying jittering when you place the mouse on the top line of the control.

Comment: Agreed but I'm actually planning on using this on visibility state change, but for ease of testing ive put it on the mouse over state. Its on a custom control (inherits off `ContentControl`)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but i think you have to supply an empty TranslateTransform to the RenderTransform, because normally there is nothing in there. So you are trying to animate something which doesn't exist. Just add the TranslateTransform and see if that works.

Comment: @dowhilefor Good idea.. how do I apply that using the Style above? (I've updated my xaml accordingly)

Comment: I could alternatively animate the margin.. this just seemed more elegant..

Comment: Got it working! Please post as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to supply an empty `TranslateTransform` to the RenderTransform, because normaly there is nothing in the `RenderTransform`. So you are trying to animate something which doesn't exist. Just add the `TranslateTransform` and see if that works:

```
<Style x:Key="blah" TargetType="Toolkit:Dialog">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Toolkit:CanvasControl.Background" Value="White" />
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="0" To="100" Duration="00:00:01.000" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style>
```