# Slide up/down animation on custom control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animatetransform

I have a panel which contains 3 custom controls. Now during runtime I only have only two of them visible at any given point in time i.e either top two or bottom two controls keeping the middle control visible at all times.

Hence, when top control is made collapsed or invisible the middle control is moved up and is shown as the top control and if bottom control is made collapsed then middle control is at the bottom.

So as for my problem I wish to animate the middle control either moving up or down. In other words animate when middle control has its location changed. Due to other controls have their visibility modified.

Could this be achieved in Wpf ? If yes then any suggestions as to how it can be achieved?

I'm using c#.

Thanks.

Edit:
Reference image depicting as to what i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Trying to animate panel B (in green) moving up and down when either panel A (in red) or panel C (in blue) have their visibility changed.

Comment: Take a look on WPF animation and render/translate transform. This question might be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927542/wpf-trigger-animation-move-control-downwards-along-y-axis

Comment: Ok I understand the storyboard will be based on render transform property. But what I don't seem to get it what will be the trigger used to start the storyboard ? Any suggestion on that @Solecki ?

Comment: Could you provide a reference picture? That would help a lot in understanding exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: i've added a reference picture as requested. hope it helps. if you require further information let me know @Solecki